# RevTeX: bibliography links include all of the citation

Tags: revtex

I am writing a paper using RevTeX, but the hyperlinks cover not only the journal name, but the volume, number / pages and year, too. I want the hyper link to be on the journal name only. MWE:

```
\documentclass[reprint,aps,prl,twocolumn, showpacs ,groupedaddress,nobibnotes]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=blue}

\begin{document}
\title{Effect of ...}
\maketitle
bla bla bla bla \cite{Bhattacharya1985}

\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\bibliography{mine}
\end{document}
```

Contents of mine.bib:

```
@article{Bhattacharya1985,
   author = {Bhattacharya, S. and Stokes, J. P. and Robbins, Mark O. and Klemm, R. A.},
   title = {Origin of Broadband Noise in CDW Conductors},
   journal = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
   volume = {54},
   number = {22},
   pages = {2453-2456},
   DOI = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.54.2453},
   url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.54.2453},
   year = {1985},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
```

Comment: I would *not* change the item(s) included in the hypertarget: If you were to change it to just the `journal` field, an incorrect umpression might arise that the link is the journal itself. By also including the volume number, the starting page, and the year in the hypertarget, it's immediately clear to any reader that the link will be to a specific article. Incidentally, it's not the document class (revtex4-1) but the bibliography style that determines all formatting aspects of the bibliographic entries.

Comment: I need to comply with the journal style, though.

Comment: Are you saying that the journal (which one, by the way?) requires you to use the style `apsrev4-1` even though it doesn't meet all formatting requirements?

Comment: It is Applied Physics Letters. It requires RevTeX 4.1. But I found all recently published papers to have the hyperlink covering the journal name only, not the whole citation.

Comment: As I noted in the initial comment, it's not the document class but the *bibliography style* that determines all formatting aspects of the bib entries. What alternatives to `apsrev4-1` do other authors use? Can you contact the journal's editorial office and ask for their recommendation for a bibliography style that actually delivers the required formatting?

Comment: Thanks, I will keep trying and at the end if I did not succeed I will have to maybe contact them.

Comment: If you want to submit to Applied Physics Letters, you have to use the class options `aip,apl` instead of `aps,prl` (which is Physical Review Letters).  This will also change the bibliography style from `apsrev4-1` to `aipauth4-1`.  If you really want to stick with `aps,prl` (the editor will hate you), then you just might change the line `\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}` to `\bibliographystyle{aipauth4-1}`.  I recommend omitting that line completely and using the `aip,apl` class options.